# Hibernate6 Issue : Unable to Fetch data of FetchType.Eager Column

Tags: hibernate

We have recently Updated to latest hibernate version, On one of the field we were using

```
@ ManyToOne(targetEntity = ConfigSet.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@ JoinColumn(name = “fk_config_set”, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ConfigSet configSet;
```

This was fetching the configSet data from DB and everything was working as expected.
But with the upgrade we are getting configSet as null (We are able to see data in DB console)

Below are the things we have tried by enabling the SQL logs :

With the existing implementation:

```
SELECT field1_alias, field2_alias, field3_alias, field4_alias, field5_alias, field6_alias, field7_alias, field8_alias, field9_alias, field10_alias, field11_alias, field12_alias, field13_alias, field14_alias, field15_alias, field16_alias, field17_alias, field18_alias
FROM pending_users pu1_0
WHERE pu1_0.id = ?
```

We are not seeing ConfigSet table in the same.

Then we tried method

```
@ Query(value = “SELECT cc FROM PendingUser cc JOIN FETCH cc.configSet WHERE cc.userUUID = :userUUID”)
on Optional findByUserUUID(UUID userUUID);
```

the below is query :

```
SELECT pu.id AS user_id, pu.extension AS user_extension, pu.email AS user_email,
cs.id AS config_id, cs.name AS config_name, cs.language AS config_language
FROM pending_users pu
JOIN config_set cs ON cs.id = pu.fk_config_set
WHERE pu.fk_users = ?
```

But the config Set is null,
We also tried

```
@ EntityGraph(value=“PendingUser.ConfigSet”)
```

SQL query :

```
SELECT pu.id AS user_id, pu.extension AS user_extension, pu.email AS user_email,
cs.id AS config_id, cs.name AS config_name, cs.language AS config_language
FROM pending_users pu
LEFT JOIN config_set cs ON cs.id = pu.fk_config_set
WHERE pu.fk_users = ?
```

Result is same. what made the fetch Type eager has caused the issue?

Posted to [hibernate community](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-eager-fetch-is-not-giving-data-in-latest-version/9223)

Comment: Did you post most of the stuff twice? It's now removed. If there was something essential somewhere hidden in between, you can restore it back.